# Where is the mirth connect transformer error stored?

Tags: mirth

Just wandering, will it be possible or the way that I can extract (or to find out) where is the com.mirth.connect.server.MirthJavascriptTransformerException stored ?

For example:
Within a channel, I write a script to call function ***abc*** (which this function is not exists). When I deployed and start the channel, I found mirth throw an exception error message and the error message can be found under the Mirth Connect Administrator Console:

```
Transformer error
ERROR MESSAGE: Error evaluating transformer
com.mirth.connect.server.MirthJavascriptTransformerException: 
CHANNEL:    Send Test Messages
CONNECTOR:  Destination 1
SCRIPT SOURCE:  TRANSFORMER
SOURCE CODE:    
352: msg = new XML(connectorMessage.getTransformedData());
353: if (msg.namespace('') != undefined) { default xml namespace = msg.namespace(''); } else { default xml namespace = ''; }
354: function doFilter() { phase[0] = 'filter'; return true; }function doTransform() { phase[0] = 'transformer'; logger = Packages.org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(phase[0]);
355: 
356: 
357: abc();
358: if ('xml' === typeof msg) {
359:     if (msg.hasSimpleContent()) {
360:         msg = msg.toXMLString();
361:     }
LINE NUMBER:    357
DETAILS:    ReferenceError: "abc" is not defined.
    at 118ddcea-ea82-4b20-9548-6b5d8df13244:357 (doTransform)
    at 118ddcea-ea82-4b20-9548-6b5d8df13244:379 (doScript)
    at 118ddcea-ea82-4b20-9548-6b5d8df13244:381
    at com.mirth.connect.server.transformers.JavaScriptFilterTransformer$FilterTransformerTask.doCall(JavaScriptFilterTransformer.java:154)
    at com.mirth.connect.server.transformers.JavaScriptFilterTransformer$FilterTransformerTask.doCall(JavaScriptFilterTransformer.java:119)
    at com.mirth.connect.server.util.javascript.JavaScriptTask.call(JavaScriptTask.java:113)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My question is, beside of under Mirth Connect Administrator Console, will this error message been stored into any log file ? (I have checked mirth.log and found nothing there).

Answer (score 2):

The folder path %installdir%\Mirth Connect\logs could have additional log files like mirth.log.1, mirth.log.2 etc in addition to the mirth.log, which is always the latest. Have you checked the serialized logs